# Importing PST to exchange overrides emails?

Tags: exchange-2010

Does importing a PST using the cmdlet override the allready present emails in the mailbox?

Comment: What do you mean "override"? Do you mean does an imported email replace an existing email? If so then the answer is yes unless you select the option during the import to not import duplicates.

Comment: That and if it would just ignore what was on the mailbox already. But i guess that answers both, you mind putting it has an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, importing mail from a PST does not overwrite what already exists in the mailbox as long as they aren't duplicates.  If there are duplicates, the mail being imported will overwrite what exists in the mailbox unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean does an imported email replace an existing email? The answer is yes unless you select the option during the import to not import duplicates

Answer (score 0):

In general, Yes, the importing emails will overwrite the existing emails if found to be the same, but all emails are not affected to overwritten. There is an attribute in PowerShell command -AssociatedMessagesCopyOption copy. Using this command, the import process will create duplicate emails if found, while importing PST files into the mailbox. For more details, visit 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboximportrequest